# Wrong answer calls on palindrome

Tags: c++, palindrome

I coded palindrome program.
I think this code is right especially is_palindrome procedure.
But I don't know why this answers wrong.

Because when I input 2 1 1, return must be This is palindrome.
But it answers the other.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_palindrome(int input[], int numOfSlots);

int main(void) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *input = new int[n]; // A dynamic array with n slots
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> input[i];
    }

    if (is_palindrome(input, n) == true) {
        cout << "This is a palindrome.";
    }
    else {
        cout << "This is NOT a palindrome.";
    }
    return 0;
}

bool is_palindrome(int input[], int numOfSlots) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < numOfSlots/2)
    {
        if (input[i] != input[numOfSlots-i])
            return false;
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `2 1 1` is not a palindrom, is it?

Comment: @zaratustra the 2 is for the size of the array.  the actual comparison happens with the `1 1` part.

Comment: You have a memory leak.  If you write `std::vector<int> input(n);` (and make the other necessary changes) it will go away.  You can also then write `bool is_palindrome(const std::vector<int>& input)` and don't have to pass the size separately.  As a general rule, avoid using a naked `new` - always encapsulated your memory allocation in `std::make_unique`, `std::vector`, or `std::make_shared` (in the rare cases where you need the latter).

Comment: I posted a [question on codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118074/determining-if-a-sequence-is-a-palindrome) with a palindrome identification algorithm if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going one past then end of the array in `if (input[i] != input[numOfSlots-i])`.  When `i == 0` then `input[numOfSlots-i]` becomes `input[numOfSlots]` which in this case is `input[2]`.  Since the last valid index of `input` is 1 you are comparing against garbage.  You should have

```
if (input[i] != input[numOfSlots-i - 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C++ are zero indexed, as `i` is initialised to `0`, on the first iteration of the loop `input[numOfSlots-i]` is out of bounds.